# won't remove automatically after it deleted from localstorage

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, local-storage, angular-local-storage

First, here's the code

**controller.js**

```
.controller('FavoritesController', ['$scope', 'dishes', 'favorites', 'favoriteFactory', 'baseURL', '$ionicListDelegate', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout', '$localStorage', function ($scope, dishes, favorites, favoriteFactory, baseURL, $ionicListDelegate, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $localStorage) {

        $scope.baseURL = baseURL;
        $scope.shouldShowDelete = false;

        $scope.favorites = favorites;

        $scope.dishes = dishes;

        console.log($scope.dishes, $scope.favorites);

        $scope.toggleDelete = function () {
            $scope.shouldShowDelete = !$scope.shouldShowDelete;
            console.log($scope.shouldShowDelete);
        }

        $scope.deleteFavorite = function (index) {

            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm Delete',
                template: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'
            });

            confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    console.log('Ok to delete');
                    favoriteFactory.deleteFromFavorites(index);

                    var old_favorite = JSON.parse($localStorage.get('favorites'));
                    var leng = Object.keys(old_favorite).length;

                    for (var i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
                        if (Object.keys(old_favorite)[i] == index) {
                            console.log("Deleted from localstorage!　" + Object.keys(old_favorite)[i]);
                            old_favorite.splice(old_favorite.indexOf(index), 1);
                            $localStorage.storeObject('favorites', old_favorite);

                        }
                    }


                } else {
                    console.log('Canceled delete');
                }
            });

            $scope.shouldShowDelete = false;

        }
    }])
```

**services.js**

```
.factory('favoriteFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {
        var favFac = {};
        var favorites = [];

        favFac.addToFavorites = function (index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index)
                    return;
            }
            favorites.push({id: index});
        };

        favFac.deleteFromFavorites = function (index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index) {
                    favorites.splice(i, 1);
                    console.log("Deleted !" + index);
                }
            }
        }

        favFac.getFavorites = function () {
            return favorites;
        };

        return favFac;
        }])
```

**favorites.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="My Favorites">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline"
          ng-click="toggleDelete()"></button>
      </div>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list show-delete="shouldShowDelete">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="dish in dishes | favoriteFilter:favorites" href="#/app/menu/{{dish.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left" on-swipe-left="deleteFavorite(dish.id)">
        <img ng-src="{{baseURL+dish.image}}" on-swipe-left="deleteFavorite(dish.id)">
        <h2>{{dish.name}}
         <span style="font-size:75%">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
        <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{dish.label}}</span></h2>
        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled"
          ng-click="deleteFavorite(dish.id)">
        </ion-delete-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
 .state('app.favorites', {
  url: '/favorites',
  views: {
    'mainContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/favorites.html',
        controller:'FavoritesController',
      resolve: {
          dishes:  ['menuFactory', function(menuFactory){
            return menuFactory.query();
          }],
                        favorites: ['favoriteFactory', function(favoriteFactory) {
              return favoriteFactory.getFavorites();
          }]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

So, after I attempt to use the deleteFavorite Function from the controller.js and the index inside the localstorage was success deleted, the data on the favorites.html couldn't updated, it couldn't deleted from the favorties.html immediately.

I need to refresh my browser first to show the up-to-date list based on the localstorage.

I hope that I can show the up-to-date data based on the localstorage data without refresh the page.

Did I make something wrong on here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try adding digest() manually to your page. Refer - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest

Comment: Create a simple demo that replicates problem

Comment: Very confusing using `index` as variable name to represent an ID. Also should do all the storage changes and array changes in same place.